# Django Admin: Change URL links in change_list page

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to change the URL links in the change_list page from default to something else.

I have gone through the code of Admin and have to say, I need help.

Can anyone help me out???
[image]

Example:
In the above pic, I want to change the link under "Abhilash Nanda" to some other link. This for all the rows I may have. I would like to go from this change list page to another change list page where I can again list the rows from a related table to the clicked link.

Comment: what is the some other link you want to change it to ?

Comment: Right now it's "/admin/HRMS/employee/1" [1 = some_number] to "/admin/HRMS/employee/something/1". In the new URL, another list will be populated which will be the foreign key related entries the to row 1 here.

Right now by default it goes to the change page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the admin URL by extending the admin model. Like this.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^my_view/$', self.my_view)
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        # custom view which should return an HttpResponse
        pass
```

You can here the full documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls).